# VarienForm js details and location

Tags: javascript, varien

I'm looking for this file but i can't seem to locate it... I know that you run this bit of javascript to turn your plain old form into VarienForm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
//]]>
</script>
```

shouldn't it be inside design/frontend/enterprise/mine/template/newsletter?

It's for an email signup on my homepage which pushes the email into a bucket and then redirects to a preference page. I believe thats what the script may do..

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
 </script>
```

above code is in file:

**app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml**

VarienForm define in file:
**js/varien/form.js**

Comment: It seems like that form.js file handles much more than simply what i first thought.  Can you elaborate on ('newsletter-validate-detail') and FormDetail.. why Detail on the end?

Comment: newsletter-validate-detail is your form id and newsletterSubscriberFormDetail is only a variable name